# Is it possible to get notification for new questions through some platform?

Tags: discussion

Last year, I was active in stackexchange but now I have so much work that I don't have time to look at the new questions or browse the old ones.

Is there is a way to get a notification when ever a question is asked in my favourite tag through facebook or google chrome or other platforms?

So for instance, I have experience in Animation nodes, would it be possible to get a notification when ever a question is asked using the AN tag?

That way I can do my work and head to stackexchange when ever I am needed.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25224/email-notifications-for-new-questions-matching-specific-tags